# Quasiconvexity + X implies convexity

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Given a continuous function $f$ that is quasi-convex over some interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$, what are examples of additional (sets of) properties (themselves weaker than convexity) that ensure that $f$ is also convex over that interval?

Comment: Quasi-convexity is a pretty weak starting point.  How are you going to use what quasi-convexity gives you (convex level sets) together with other features to get to convexity?

Comment: I doubt there's any particularly interesting answer here. I'll bet any additional condition people think of will get you convexity _by itself_.